# What is this display technique called? Where you create 3 or 4 columns and populate them with different height result tiles

Tags: css

this isn't a coding problem but I wanted to know the common name given to the a certain display technique for product search results.

I know you have "Grid" and "List" but this one is where you create 3 or 4 columns and populate them with different height result tiles. [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com) do it in their browse pages and eBay kind of does it on their 'Following' tab on their home page.

I'm thinking it's called 'Waterfall' but wasn't too sure.

Comment: I removed your link because it was redirecting to home page. Please try to find a new link or image to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 'masonry' list items

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I would never have thought to call it that.

Comment: it is also called tiles layout

Comment: windows 8 made it more popular i think and instagram

Comment: I know it's tough looking for something not knowing how it's called. glad I could help